Ecclesiastical Latin average word length
Does anyone know of how long the average word in ecclesiastical latin is? Are the sources or papers on the topic?

How exactly are you defining "ecclesiastical Latin"? Papal encyclicals? Scholastic theologians? My first thought is that the Corpus Thomisticum is a vast digitization of the works of Aquinas, but I'm not sure if he's a representative sample of what you're looking for.

Update: added an Encyclical and reworded some of the text accordingly

Welcome to the site!
Since you don't specify it further, I'll assume you needed an approximate value and did not really care about which period of time and/or corpus to use, which may make the answer vary a lot, as you'll see below.
I took three different texts and tried the following (with Python):

Made sure I knew about what character set the text was using. (Are there special characters like á, æ, ö? The text I used avoid these altogether, which makes the job slightly easier).
Remove anything that was not a space or a valid text character. (Quotes, punctuation, chapter numbers...)
Remove extra spaces. (My text had lots of them. It also had the title repeated over and over, so I removed it so as to avoid biasing the results.)
Counted total characters and total words. At this point if there are M words, there must be M-1 spaces that must be handled to avoid counting them as part of word length.
Divided characters by words to get word length.

Tried it with books from the Vulgate, (arguable late Latin, though,) and the Fides et Ratio encyclical (1998), and got the following:
Book of Revelation (Apocalypsis):
total valid letters = 42,784
total words = 8,469
avg. word length=5.05

Gospel of Matthew (Matthaeus):
total valid letters = 86,613
total words = 16,655
avg. word length = 5.20

Fides et Ratio: (I also trimmed the notes and a few header links here.)
total valid letters = 161,809
total words = 24,892
avg. word length = 6.50

(The avg. might be higher, since my quick processing left a little html-related short-length garbage.)
This highlights the issue pointed out by @brianpck in the comments: with different texts you will get different results. It depends a lot on the text, and you'll need a curated, huge, varied, corpus to get an average for the whole language. There are big differences between cultured text like an Encyclical or the Summa Theologiae and the New Testament, which is a translation of a book whose target audience is much more massive and is intended to be written in simple terms.
Another important issue is how to treat ligatures: Do you count æ as one character or two? For what it's worth, I counted them as two. It was easiest, since that's how my corpus represented them.
